# Distort image to make raindrop on screen effect

Tags: ios, opengl-es, core-image

I want to make an image appear distorted as if raindrops are on the screen. [Image of water droplet effect over check pattern http://db.tt/fQkx9bzh](http://db.tt/fQkx9bzh)

Any idea how I could do this using OpenGL or CoreImage?

I am able get an image with the depth of the raindrop shapes if that helps. Otherwise, I'm really not sure how to do this especially as they are not perfectly circular and I have almost no experience with OpenGL or Core Image (although I can set up the buffers and stuff and do some simple drawing).

Comment: I could try and fake it by just masking a larger version of the background but I don't think that would look too great.

Comment: No, a simple enlargement of the background would be completely wrong. This is probably a trivial exercise for a ray tracing package. I could possibly throw together something that would roughly simulate it, but it wouldn't be in your choice of technologies.

Comment: What do you mean by "it wouldn't be in your choice of technologies"? Could you do it in another language?

Comment: I mean I can't provide an answer in OpenGL or Core Image. It would be in Python, so I'm not sure how useful it would be to you or if a simpler solution might be possible with the capabilities of those packages.

Comment: Ah, I see. Something like this flash demo that I just found might work. If you think it might be simpler.

Comment: Hmm...just realised I kinda just asked for the same thing but said it in a different way.

Comment: [This is the link to the flash demo](http://www.quasimondo.com/archives/000561.php#000561) incase your still interested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use the elevation of the drop (that is, distance from the surface) as control texture for a [Bulge effect](http://web.archive.org/web/20100622030108/http://dem.ocracy.org/libero/photobooth/). Use the barycenter of the drop as the centerpoint for the effect.

Comment: On the locating of the barycenter: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locating_the_center_of_mass
A control texture is used like a parameter. That is, you sample the control texture to get per-pixel parameter values. In this case, you might use it to convey intensity mapping for your bulge effect.

Comment: Thanks, I think I get the control texture now. The thing about the centre was that I knew what the barycentre was but just couldn't figure out how to move the centre for the bulge effect. The only way I can see to do it is to move the texture before applying the effect and then move it back. Surely this is the wrong way to do it. Here is the simple code I have at the moment:

Comment: ` vec2 texCoord = gl_TexCoord[0].xy;
 vec2 normCoord = 2.0 * texCoord - 1.0;  
 float r = length(normCoord);  
 r = r * smoothstep(-0.1, 0.5, r);  
 float phi = atan(normCoord.y, normCoord.x);  
 normCoord.x = r * cos(phi);  
 normCoord.y = r * sin(phi);  
 texCoord = normCoord / 2.0 + 0.5;  
 gl_FragColor = texture2D(tex, texCoord);  `

Comment: There's an example of displacement using a control texture here: http://vvvv.org/contribution/displacement-map
Basically, you sample the control texture in very much the same way as the "image" texture. But, you use the values differently. Simply put, you ought to supply a depth map as the control texture.
PS: You may upvote comments if they are helpful.

Comment: Does this mean I need to make a pixel and a vertex shader? Or is it possible with just a pixel shader?

Comment: Or could I just use a vertex shader alone to change the height of a mesh according to the control texture?

Comment: OMG, I got it working perfectly with a vertex shader!! I've never even looked at opengl before (and am quite new to programming altogether) so I'm super happy! :) Thank you so much!!